# Sorting in three fragments in single activity

Tags: java, android

I have implemented Sorting in three fragments. The problem is that if I comment the last two fragment-sort functions, first fragment-sort works fine but if I uncomment the second and the third fragment Sort is not working. Can u please help me with this. What am I doing wrong? 
    Here my doubt is i am using same text view id for three fragments

Comment: I suggest that you post only the relevant portions of your code (i.e. the code you think is causing your problem). The code you posted is really long and not everyone has the patience to look through long code :).

Comment: Yes sorry and sometimes they say like code is not enough so i putted all and my problem is i implemented sorting in fragments but it is working in first form not in second and third.

Comment: Comment out all 3 sort functions. Then test the app. If all 3 fragments instantiate without problems, then the error must be in your sort function. Also, post the error that you're getting from logcat?

Comment: No there is no problem with sort, what i am saying is sort will work only if other sort fun are commented. If those are uncommented it will not work and i am implementing same sort in all three only diffrent adapters

Comment: @samlorry I think we need more verbose code. There is a main activity hosting the 3 fragments in a fragmentpageradapter right? Try shifting the sort function to the main activity and calling it from the fragments.

Comment: No it is not possible, because i am adding sorting result to SetListadapter and i can't cal List adapter outside the fragments. One doubt is i am using single XML and single textview to all. is there any problem using like this

Comment: @samlorry post the error that you're getting in logcat

Comment: 03-19 15:34:24.584: I/MaliEGL(9530): [Mali]max_allowed_dequeued_buffers=3
03-19 15:34:24.616: I/MaliEGL(9530): [Mali]window_type=1, is_framebuffer=0, errnum = 0
03-19 15:34:24.616: I/MaliEGL(9530): [Mali]surface->num_buffers=4, surface->num_frames=3, win_min_undequeued=1